# Consultas preparadas PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando realizar la siguiente consulta a mi base de datos, para luego compararla con la contraseña que ingreso el usuario la cual esta encriptada, pero no logro hacer que funcione. adjunto código que estoy trabajando:

```
//Obtienes los datos enviados por el formulario
$email=$_POST['email'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];


try {
    //conexion a bd
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=registro_usuario', 'root', '');

    //sentencia a ejecutar
    $comando = $pdo->prepare("SELECT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email=?");

    //asigno valor al campo email
    $comando->execute([$email]);

    //extraigo el resultado
    $resultado = $comando->fetchAll();

    //compruebo el resultado con la contraseña ingresada anteriormente por el usuario
    if (password_verify($contraseña, $resultado)) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
    } else {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }

} catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo $ex-getMessage();
}
```

Comment: El método adecuado para este caso no es `fetchAll()`, el cual te crea un array con los resultados. Es mejor usar `fetchColumn()`. Prueba a ponerlo así: `$resultado = $comando->fetchColumn();` Otra cosa: evita usar `ñ` y acentos en nombres de variables, tablas, columnas. Si no hilas fino con la codificación variables como `contraseña` podrían romper el código.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió, era tal cual lo que decías, reemplace mi código por `$resultado = $comando->fetchColumn();` y muchas gracias por el consejo de como escribir nombres de variables, soy nuevo en todo esto y cualquier información me viene mas que bien @A.Cedano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método adecuado para este caso no es `fetchAll()`, el cual te crea un array con los resultados. Es mejor usar [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), dado que estás seleccionando una sola columna que es `contraseña`.

Prueba a ponerlo así:

```
$resultado = $comando->fetchColumn();
```

Salvo otros errores, debería funcionar.

Otra cosa: evita usar `ñ` y acentos en nombres de variables, tablas, columnas. Si no hilas fino con la codificación variables/columnas como `contraseña` podrían romper el código.